# how to detect a text box value has been changed by jquery and if value is changed then call an ajax function

Tags: jquery

i wanna call jquery function on change of textbox1 and value of textbox1 is being filled by textbox not by keyboard or any mouse event so kindly help me out 
thanks in advance

This is a demo code

```
<p><input id = "textbox" onkeyup="fillVal()" type = "text"></p>
<p><input id = "textbox1" type = "text"></p>
<span></span>

<script>

$("#textbox1").on("change", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
function fillVal()
{
    document.getElementById('textbox1').value=document.getElementById('textbox').value
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to use JQuery event [URL](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 2):

call [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change);

```
$("#textbox1").on("change", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});

function fillVal()
{
    document.getElementById('textbox1').value=document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    $("#textbox1").change();
}
```

**OR**

```js
$("#textbox1").on("change", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});

function fillVal() {
  $ '#textbox1').val($('#textbox').val()).change();
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It is working. I did not saw `$("#textbox1").change();` +1

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
$("#textbox1").on("keyup", function() {
   fillVal()
});
function fillVal()
{
   $("#textbox").val($("#textbox1").val())
}
```

Comment: This wont work. You can try it.Please post tested and verified code.

Answer (score 0):

Do all your code in fillVal()

```
function fillVal()
{
    document.getElementById('textbox1').value=document.getElementById('textbox').value
alert(document.getElementById('textbox1').value); 

}
```

or use a common function:

```
function trig(el) {
  alert(el.val());
}
$("#textbox1").on("change", function() {
   trig($(this))
});

function fillVal()
{
    document.getElementById('textbox1').value=document.getElementById('textbox').value;
trig($("#textbox1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like something like this,

```
<p><input id = "textbox" onkeyup="fillVal()" type = "text"></p>
<p><input id = "textbox1" type = "text"></p>
<span></span>

<script>
    $("#textbox1").on("keyup", function() {
      $("#textbox").val($("#textbox1").val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in your code, you can have a look on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hearty/uctaxwbb/4/)

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function() {
  $("#textbox1").val($(this).val()).change();
});
```